# Calculate normal distribution from $\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d([f(x)])}{dx} = \frac{d-x}{a}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics

Calculate normal distribution from $\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d([f(x)])}{dx} = \frac{d-x}{a+bx+cx^2}$ when $b=c=0$ then we have $\frac{d-x}{a}$. This is taken from Mathematical Statistics with Applications by John Freund.

I know the differential equation can be split like-so:
$$\int\frac{d([f(x)])}{f(x)}=\int\frac{(d-x)dx}{a} \\ \implies \ln f(x) = \frac{2dx-x^2}{2a}+c$$

My issue is that the solution booklet shows $$\ln f(x) = -\frac{(d-x)^2}{2a}+c$$

I can only partially see this working if I simplify the quadratic

$$\ln f(x) = -\frac{(d-x)^2-d^2}{2a}+c$$

Is there a mistake in the solutions manual, or perhaps I've missed something obvious?

Book reference:
Page 194, exercise 32 (Chapter 6- Eight edition).

Answer (score 1):

$f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are both indefinite integral of the same function iff $f_1-f_2$ is a constant function.

Use this for the RHS, taking solution manual answer as $f_1$ and yours as $f_2$.